# How to know how healthy an SQL Server database is now?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2012

I want to know how healthy an SQL Server database is now (before I started to work with it).

Then, in a month or so, I want to check again to see how healthy database is at that time and compare it to the previous state.

Basically is there any way I can take something like a snapshot of the database health now and later? And then see what's been improved, so I can track my progress.

Any source of information would be great.

Comment: That's way too broad, I'm afraid. "Health" of a server means different things to different people. Once you define what a "healthy SQL Server" means to you with your workload and SLA, you'll be half-way through to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at sp_blitzfirst from [www.brentozar.com](http://www.brentozar.com)
This store procedure will give you a good status of your SQL servers.

Answer (score 1):

There are also a series of Brent's First Responder files here - https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit.

As Dominique says, sp_blitz_first is the one you want.